# Error creating table using Hibernate Schema Updater

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm facing problems using Hibernate Schema Updater. The statement Hibernate fires at server startup is:

```html
create table Match (id integer not null, guest varchar(255), home varchar(255), matchDate varchar(255), matchDay varchar(255), matchNumber varchar(255), resultPoints varchar(255), resultSets varchar(255), venue varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

I tried that statement on the commandline without success. However, if i prepend the database name to the table name, it works:

```html
create table ivolley.Match (id integer not null, guest varchar(255), home varchar(255), matchDate varchar(255), matchDay varchar(255), matchNumber varchar(255), resultPoints varchar(255), resultSets varchar(255), venue varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

Has anyone an idea how to tell Hibernate or the database to use that prefix?

Here is my persistence.xml:

```html
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ivolley" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description></description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/Volleynator</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.chopper.ivolley.server.entities.Match</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thanks, Eddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `default_schema` setting:

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="ivolley" />
```